# Form validation not working after adding password validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am learning `JavaScript` and working on `form validation`. I have a simple form that asks for several different fields to be filled out.

I had my form validation working. I then added a function to check if the password fields matched. This also checks while the user is typing. The second function works just fine but now the rest of my form validation as stopped functioning all together.

Any push here would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<title>Marty the Robot | About</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/source.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js""></script>

</head>

<body>

<main>

<div class="signupform-container">


 <div id="form-title">
      <h2>
           Create an account
      </h2>
 </div>
<form method="post" action="" id="submitForm">
    <div id="validation"></div>

    <div id="field1-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Name<br>
    <div class="space">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="FName" placeholder="enter your first name"></label>
    </div>

    <div id="field2-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Last Name<br>
    <div class="space">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="LName" placeholder="enter your last name"></label>
    </div>

    <div id="field3-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Email<br>
    <div class="space">
    </div>    
    <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="email@email.com"></label>
    </div>

    <div id="field4-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Username<br>
    <div class="space">
    </div>    
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="enter a username"></label>
    </div>

    <div id="field5-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Password<br>
    <input type="password" id="txtNewPassword" placeholder="enter a password" />
    </div>

    <div id="field6-container" class="field-container">
    <label>Password<br>
    <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="enter your password again" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" />
    </div>

    <div id="field7-container" class="field-container">
    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">
    </div>


    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch">

    <div id="form-submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Make it so">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function Validate(form) {
    var errors = "";
    if (form.Name.value.length === 0) {
        form.Name.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter your first name</li>";
    }
    if (form.LName.value.length === 0) {
        form.LName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.LName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter your last name</li>";
    }
    if (form.Username.value.length === 0) {
        form.Username.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Username.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter a username</li>";
    }        
    if (form.Email.value.length === 0) {
        form.Email.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Email.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter an email address</li>";
    }
    if (form.Password1.value.length <= 4) {
        form.Password1.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Password1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Your password is not long enough</li>";
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = "<ul>" + errors + "</ul>";
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
document.getElementById("submitForm").onsubmit = function () {
return Validate(this);
};

</script>

<script>
function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#confirmpassword").val();

if (password !== confirmPassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});


</script>

</div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

**Validation code**

```
<script>
function Validate(form) {
    var errors = "";
    if (form.FName.value.length === 0) {
        form.FName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.FName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter your first name</li>";
    }
    if (form.LName.value.length === 0) {
        form.LName.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.LName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter your last name</li>";
    }
    if (form.Username.value.length === 0) {
        form.Username.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Username.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter a username</li>";
    }        
    if (form.Email.value.length === 0) {
        form.Email.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Email.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Please enter an email address</li>";
    }
    if (form.Password1.value.length <= 4) {
        form.Password1.style.border = "1px solid red";
        form.Password1.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
        errors += "<li>Your password is not long enough</li>";
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = "<ul>" + errors + "</ul>";
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
document.getElementById("submitForm").onsubmit = function () {
return Validate(this);
};

</script>

<script>
function checkPasswordMatch() {
var password = $("#password").val();
var confirmPassword = $("#confirmpassword").val();

if (password !== confirmPassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords do not match!");
else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html("Passwords match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});


</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/martylavender/n0tb7n4e/

Comment: Could you post your validation code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue with my validation of the password field being more than X number of characters and my separate function that was validating the password1 and password2 matched.

During testing, I removed the validation of the password minimum length and the rest of the form validation worked along with the password match function.

Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo here

```
form.Name.value.length
```

There **is no** input with **name="Name"**

Change it to this:

```
form.FName.value.length
```

Like this:

```
if (form.FName.value.length === 0) {
    form.FName.style.border = "1px solid red";
    form.FName.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
    errors += "<li>Please enter your first name</li>";
}
```

It works.

Comment: I did in fact have a typo. I noticed now when I try to submit the form without any fields filled out, they all blink red as if they are trying to validate but then the form appears to reset.

Comment: appears to reset means what?

Comment: My last comment should have been a little more clear perhaps. The form fields flash as if the validation is firing but then the form resets. My password validation function works.